# Displaying members using php three rows three column

Tags: php, html, arrays

I created three columns and three rows using `li`; I want to display one member in every `li` order by id.

```
<li>                   // Style: margin-bottom:10px;
    Show first member result here...
</li>

<li class="middle_li"> // Style: margin:0px 10px 10px;
    Show second member result here...
</li>

<li>                   // Style: margin-bottom:10px;
    Show third member result here...
</li>


<li>                   // Style: margin-bottom:10px;
    Show first member result here...
</li>

<li class="middle_li"> // Style: margin:0px 10px 10px;
    Show second member result here...
</li>

<li>                   // Style: margin-bottom:10px;
    Show third member result here...
</li>


<li>                   // Style: margin-bottom:10px;
    Show first member result here...
</li>

<li class="middle_li"> // Style: margin:0px 10px 10px;
    Show second member result here...
</li>

<li>                   // Style: margin-bottom:10px;
    Show third member result here...
</li>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
    require 'initialize.inc.php';    // Classes: connection & members
    echo '<ul>';
    $members = $member->display_members();
    foreach ($members as $member)
    {
        $html_ouput = '<li>';
        $html_ouput .= 'Show member result here...';
        $html_ouput .= '</li>';
        echo $html_output;
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

This php code display nine results. Three columns three rows but how can I give every second `li` row a class middle? Any modification in my php code? I don't want to use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
<?php
require 'initialize.inc.php';    // Classes: connection & members
echo '<ul>';
$members = $member->display_members();
$i = 0;
foreach ($members as $member)
{
    $html_ouput = ($i % 3 == 1 ? '<li class="middle">' : '<li>');
    $html_ouput .= 'Show member result here...';
    $html_ouput .= '</li>';
    echo $html_output;
    $i++;
}
echo '</ul>';
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the string to output

try this:

```
<?php
    require 'initialize.inc.php';    // Classes: connection & members
    echo '<ul>';
    $members = $member->display_members();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($members as $member)
    {
        $html_ouput = '';
        $i++;
        if($i == 1)
           $html_ouput .= '<li>';
        else{
           $i = 0;
           $html_ouput .= '<li class="middle">';
        }
        $html_ouput .= 'Show member result here...';
        $html_ouput .= '</li>';
        echo $html_output;
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter in the for each loop and test to see if the counter is divisible by 2... If it is then its an even number. If it is an even number add the class="middle".